# What does the Battle Cleric's Lore +2 shield bonus mean when I'm not proficient with shields?

Tags: dnd-4e

I've created a Templar Cleric with Battle Cleric's Lore and it says that I get +2 shield bonus to AC with this Lore. I'm confused though, because I'm not proficient with shields.

Could anyone please help me to explain this? And can a templar Cleric use shields in general (I don't need my two-handed morningstar because I don't have any melee powers and don't need MBAs)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct that you are not proficient with shields, so carrying around a shield will not help you unless you pickup that proficiency from somewhere else.

What the ability means is that you get a +2 bonus to your AC. The type of bonus is a shield bonus, which means it won't stack with other shield bonuses to AC (you get whatever the largest is), but it will stack with feat or power bonuses. This bonus is granted by the class feature, and does not require you to have a shield.

Comment: This is really unclear on the primary point that *a shield bonus is not the same thing as actually carrying around a shield.*

Answer (score 10):

**Shield bonus is a bonus type**

Simply add the +2 to your AC. Shield is type of bonus being given. In 4e bonuses of the same type do not stack (however untyped bonuses do). Thus you would not benefit at all from wearing an actual shield while having Battle Cleric's Lore as a feature.  FYI some other examples of bonus types used are feat bonus and power bonus.

Comment: Thanks, got this. Then I have 1 more question - what weapon should be my aim? Morningstar seems pretty useless... Now I got a defensive staff that gives +1 to my defenses but maybe there is some better option for clerics?

Comment: @OleksandrGalichenko sounds like a great topic for another separate question. "Which weapons are best to optimized for Battle Clerics?"